# When weighted $L^2-$norm are comparable?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ be a measurable function.
Let $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb N$ such that $r_1+r_2=r.$

> Question:Can we expect  $$\int_{\mathbb R^2} |x|^{2r} |f(x)|^2 dx \leq C \int_{\mathbb R^2} x_1^{2r_1}x_2^{2r_2}|f(x)|^2 dx$$ for some constant $C>0$?

Edit: $(x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb R^2, |x|^{2r}= (x_1^2+ x_2^2)^r$

Using the hint given below, I have tried to do this. 
$\int_{\mathbb R^2}|x|^{2r}|f|^2 \leq C \int_{\mathbb R^2} x_1^{2r_1+2r_2}|f|^2 dx + C \int_{\mathbb R^2} x_2^{2r_1+2r_2}|f|^2 dx $.

From this I do not know how to proceed? (Maybe I have to compare $x_1$ and $x_2$?)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** use the inequality 
$$
1\le\frac{(x+y)^p}{x^p+y^p}\le2^{p-1}
$$
which holds for all $x,y>0$ in which $p>1$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it true that $1\leq \frac{(\sum_{j}x_j)^r}{\sum_{j}x_j^r} \leq C$ for $x_i$ positives? where should I look for the proof? (I mean  of finite sum)

Comment: Thanks.  Using your hint I have tried to proceed (see edited question). But I do not know how to get the desired inequality? Please could you tell bit more? Thanks..